# mvvm Pass button click to parent

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

Note: this is a different question to the one here: [Pass dependency property to child view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579156/pass-dependency-property-to-child-view)

I am currently creating a usercontrol in wpf which consists of several 'screens' that the user will click through.

For each 'screen' I have created a view with it's own viewmodel (e.g. View1.xaml, View2.xaml). The main usercontrol can then access these views:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:ModuleBaseViewModel x:Key="ViewModelDataSource" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelDataSource}}">
    <local:View1 Visibility="Visible"/>
    <local:View2 Visibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
```

I would like to pass a button click from a view back down to the parent usercontrol so that I can hide that view and show the next one. Can someone explain to me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to create an event in each view that is fired when the button is clicked, like `OnButtonClicked`, then your user control can register to the event

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM and WPF, chances are you are using an IoC container.  Almost every IoC container contains a method of publishing an event and then subscribing to that event.  In Prism, the code looks something like this:

```
EventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeEvent>().Publish(ParametersHere)
```

I would suggest you look at your options for publishing events and reacting to them.  Then your parent view model can respond to the children's events.